# Where do I find the name displayed in "Devices and Printers"

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, bluetooth, device

I have a serial device connected via Bluetooth. It shows up nicely on COM4. I can communicate with it without a problem.

I want to make it simpler for the user to locate (ideally, I'll auto-detect it), so I want to find it by name. In the "Devices and Printers" list, I get a valid name, which is perfect. However, I can't seem to find that value programatically. I've tried a ton of stuff using the "ManagementObjectSearcher" class, including listing out all the Properties and SystemProperties, but no values match the name displayed in "Devices and Printers".

If I look in the "Device Manager" list, it just shows "Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM4)", which is not useful for identifying it, obviously.

So how the heck to I get the displayed name in the "Devices and Printers" list?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This is perfect for printers, but doesn't include any non-printer devices; which mine is.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution. I grabbed the library from these guys:

http://32feet.codeplex.com/

Using that library, added these 2 lines:

```
BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices();
```

That gave me the device "DeviceName" (the name I was after) and "DeviceAddress" (a chunk of the device id, basically).

I then queried the system using the "ManagementObjectSearcher", which gave me a list of COM ports and device IDs (System.Management namespace).

```
ConnectionOptions options = ProcessConnection.ProcessConnectionOptions();
ManagementScope connectionScope = ProcessConnection.ConnectionScope(Environment.MachineName, options, @"\root\CIMV2");

ObjectQuery objectQuery = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");
ManagementObjectSearcher comPortSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(connectionScope, objectQuery);

...etc as I looped over the results, pulled out the COM ports, and so on
```

I mapped the device IDs from the "ManagementObject" values back to the "devices" list, merged the results, and ended up with something that had the name, device id, a flag indicating if it was a bluetooth device, and the "human readable" name from the bluetooth device, if it existed.

Painful, but it works fairly well. It's slow (client.DiscoverDevices() takes awhile), but that's survivable in my case.